# Sql query returns twice the suspected value on some occasions and the correct on others

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query which joins 3 tables together. But I sometimes I get result that is twice what I expect.

For example if I run the query with `s.Driver_Id = 15000` a total which is twice the stage time.
But if I run the sane query with `s.Driver_Id = 15001` I get the expected result.

Here is an SQL Fiddle link to my tables and SQL query http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3204ea/12

Any help would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are `INNER JOIN`ing to `driverevent` which has multiple rows per driver - each for a different event, but you're only joining on `driver_id`. So if that `driver_id` appears on 3 `driverevent` records, you end up `JOIN`ing all 3 rows even though. What you need to do is `JOIN ON driver_id and event_id`.

```
INNER JOIN driverevent de
    on d.licence_no = de.driver_id and s.Event_Id = de.Event_Id
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3204ea/25/0)

---

On closer inspection Alan, it appears to me that the logic behind your query may be wrong. As far as I can tell you don't need to be doing any `GROUP`ing or `SUM`ing at all.

I could be incorrect since I don't know the real world logic of the query, however consider this query with the `GROUP BY` and `SUM`s removed - [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3204ea/32/0)

Answer (score 0):

You simply have two records with `driver_id` 15000 in the driverevent table.